# String from data base for array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, push, slice

Hi I am looking for some help, what I've done is sent the values of the selected pictures I want for my blog article and pushed them all into and array and when I submit my form the pictures "Array" saves to the data base like so

TABLE

```
article_id  file_name          title  body         date            author
1           img1.jpg           lorem  lorem ipsum  11/11/2103      mitchell
2           img2.jpg,img3.jpg  lorem  lorem ipsum  11/11/2013      mitchell
```

but what I need help on is when I echo out article_id = 2 I need to have them stored in a array like this

```
$list = array(1 => 'img2.jpg', 2 => 'img3.jpg');
```

Thank you in advance for any help / advice.

Comment: You haven't heard of [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode)?

Comment: `var` is Javascript, not PHP. (Also, `list` is reserved in PHP.) What language is the question in?

Comment: Thank you so much hahaha no I haven't heard of explode I've be trying to figure this out for 30 mins now haha thanks, sorry I've just start web development school and we haven't gone over that yet thanks a lot!

Comment: Please upvote also if the answer helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this dude.....

```
 $result = 'img2.jpg,img3.jpg';

  $res = explode(',',$result);

  print_r($result);
```

For sample example please look into this [link](http://eval.in/9643) and for reference of [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) go through this link.

Answer (score 0):

Select all data from database for article_id = 2

```
$images    = $result['file_name'];

$img_array = explode(",",$images);

print_r($img_array);
```